# Adding Days to Current Date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

All I want to do is to add 20 days to the current date. I need the results in mm/dd/yyyy format.  Today is 05/15/2014 but this displays 05/35/2014 which of course is not a valid date.

```
var myDate = new Date();
alert((myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (myDate.getDate() + 20) + "/" +   myDate.getFullYear());
```

Comment: A bit of research is all you needed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: don't add directly to getDate, instead use `myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate + 20)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) method of your Date object, passing the current date plus the number of days to add.

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 20);

alert((myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (myDate.getDate()) + "/" +   myDate.getFullYear());
```

Outputs

> 6/4/2014